# Behaviour of harmonic oscillator when elastic constant$\to +\infty$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, physics, mathematical-physics

I have a silly question about asymptotics and physical meaning.
Suppose you have this equation here

\begin{align*}
x'' + \dfrac{k}{m}\,x &= -g \\
x(0) &= x_0 \\
x'(0) &= v_0.
\end{align*}

Assuming I did all my calculations right the solution is something like

$$
x(t) = \left(x_0 - \frac{m}{k}\,g\right) \cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\,t \right) + \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}\,v_0 \sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\,t\right) - \frac{m}{k}\,g.
$$

Now if I let $k\to +\infty$ I get $x(t) \sim x_0 \cos\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}}\,t \right)$ which is kind of unexpected in some sense and I'd like to know if the interpretation I am giving is correct:

1. If $x_0 = 0$ then the system is not affected by the gravity at all, initial velocity won't matter and there's only one dominant term in the asymptotic expansion.
2. If $x_0 \neq 0$ the system will oscillate indefinitely, this bit was not really expected.

I was expecting to see the system completely still no matter what with an extremely stiff spring.

Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Why is it unexpected?  You put an extremely large restoring force on the particle so it will oscillate very quickly but the amplitude is basically the same (especially if you measure from equilibrium instead).

Comment: I was expecting with an extremely stiff spring not to move at all no matter what force you apply.

Comment: but you started with the particle not in equilibrium, so it **must** move.  If the initial conditions were $x(0)=mg/k$ then the amplitude of the resulting motion indeed $\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what occurs when you let $k\to\infty,$ I would divide your DE through by $k:$
$$\frac{x''}{k} + \frac{1}{m}\,x = -\frac{g}{k}.$$
Then you can see that the far left term and the RHS go to zero, and you're left with $\dfrac{x}{m}=0,$ or $x=0,$ which is what you'd expect with an infinitely stiff spring.

Comment: What assumptions are you making on $x''$ to have $x''/k \to 0$?

Comment: Stupid side question. If I discretized the equation (say with forward Euler) would I get the same result?

Comment: Not many assumptions. Because $x$ represents the physical location of a spring, it's going to have regularity conditions on it. It's likely bounded. That's all you need.

Comment: But at $t=0$ you have a very large $x''$ if $x(0)\ne 0$

Comment: This is a physical system of a mass suspended by a spring. $x''$ may be very large, but it must still be finite. The mass cannot instantaneously tunnel from one location to another. So as $k\to\infty,$ $x''/k\to 0.$

Comment: So how do you account for the initial condition? What's the acceleration at $t=0$, say for $x(0)=1$?

Comment: @Andrei Oh, I think I see what you're saying: if you re-arrange the DE to $x''=-g-kx/m,$ then the initial acceleration looks like it's infinite. Again, I would go back to a physical argument coupled with a mathematical one. Mathematically, in a limit, you never actually *arrive* at the limiting value (in this case, $k$ never arrives at $\infty.$) You would have to increase $k$ physically. As you do so, the above DE is not accurate, since $k$ is a function of time. If you were able to solve that DE, I think you'd find a hard-damped oscillator would be the result.

Comment: I agree. Physically $k\to \infty$ and $x(0)\ne0$ are hard to obtain.